# PHP: wrapping a string into a file object

Tags: php, string, file, web-crawler, fopen

quick question:

So I've written a bunch of crawling code, but one of the websites I'm crawling didn't include line breaks between tags. Since I've already written a bunch of code, I threw in a quick hack with preg_replace and continued from where I left off. Problem is, fopen() doesn't work on strings...

```
$string = file_get_contents($url);
$string = preg_replace("/>(^\n|\n+)?</", ">\n<", $string);
$file = fopen($string, 'r');
while(($buffer = fgets($file)) != false) { ... }
```

So, without rewriting my loop, how do I approach this?

Thanks for the help!

Rob

Comment: It's weird desire. ... Why you want to do it?

Comment: I don't want to rewrite my loop :P lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're looking to iterate over each line of the fetched page. You can do this after you've pulled it into a string by using the [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to break the string into an array at the line breaks:

```
foreach (explode("\n", $string) as $line) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: omg duh! lol, thanks alex! that'll only take a quick refactor to implement